# Chaincode container was not started when commit Chaincode by using fabric-sdk-node in fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using fabric-node-sdk to handle fabric network. The version is fabric-client:2.0.0-snapshot.326
The Chaincode images were generated after install.
When I commit the chaincode, it returns success but the chaincode container was not started.